# R - How to count the number of files in each folder

Tags: r

I have a folder with many subfolder and I want to know: 
1. The number of files in each subfolder
2. Whether that number is odd or even (but this is minor)

So, I'm looking for a code/function where the **input** is the PATH and the **output** is a table with: 
SUBDIRECTORY ; # of files ; ODD/EVEN

Suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Base `R` comes with a handy function for this called `list.files`. Using the pattern argument you can narrow down your search (`"."` gives you all files). Using `all.files = TRUE` you could also include hidden files.

```
folder <- "C:/Users/Johannes Gruber/Pictures"
files <-  list.files(folder, pattern = ".", all.files = FALSE, recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)

# number of all files
length(files)
#> [1] 182
```

You can use `split` to split up this vector into a list with the content of each folder in separate list elements.

```
# 1. The number of files in each subfolder
dir_list <- split(files, dirname(files))
files_in_folder <- sapply(dir_list, length)
head(files_in_folder)
#>                 C:/Users/Pictures 
#>                                                10 
#> C:/Users/Pictures/2019/2019-12-30 
#>                                                 3 
#> C:/Users/Pictures/2019/2019-12-31 
#>                                                 9 
#> C:/Users/Pictures/2020/2020-01-01 
#>                                                 6 
#> C:/Users/Pictures/2020/2020-01-03 
#>                                                 2 
#> C:/Users/Pictures/2020/2020-01-04 
#>                                                26

# 2. Whether that number is odd or even (but this is minor)
even <- sapply(files_in_folder, function(x) x %% 2 == 0)
head(even)
#>                 C:/Users/Pictures 
#>                                              TRUE 
#> C:/Users/Pictures/2019/2019-12-30 
#>                                             FALSE 
#> C:/Users/Pictures/2019/2019-12-31 
#>                                             FALSE 
#> C:/Users/Pictures/2020/2020-01-01 
#>                                              TRUE 
#> C:/Users/Pictures/2020/2020-01-03 
#>                                              TRUE 
#> C:/Users/Pictures/2020/2020-01-04 
#>                                              TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tidyverse option where I create a tibble (data frame) with a single variable `subfolder` containing the subfolder names. Then I `mutate`, adding `file_n` by iterating over the combined `path` + `subfolder` in `str_glue`, passing to `dir` and getting the length of the returned vector with `length`. In the final step I simply return `TRUE` if `file_n` is even, and `FALSE` otherwise, in variable `is_even`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

path <- "~/folder/"

tibble(subfolder = dir(path)) %>% 
    mutate(file_n = map_int(str_glue("{path}{subfolder}"), ~ dir(.) %>% length),
           is_even = file_n %% 2 == 0
           )
```

#### Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  subfolder  file_n is_even
  <chr>       <int> <lgl>  
1 subfolder1      1 FALSE  
2 subfolder2      2 TRUE   
3 subfolder3      3 FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

nice approach by @user10191355 but only this one is working for me

```
library(tidyverse)
path <- "~/folder/"
tibble(f = paste0(path,"/",dir(path))) %>% 
rowwise() %>%
mutate(n = dir(f) %>% length)
```

this comes in handy if you are interested in subdirectories as well

```
library(stringr)    
tibble(f= paste0(path,"/",dir(path,recursive=TRUE,include.dirs=TRUE))) %>%
filter(!str_detect(f,"\\.")) %>%
rowwise() %>%
mutate(n = dir(f) %>% length)
```